# Why isn't phonegap picking up my res/icon/ios icons?

Tags: cordova

In config.xml I still have the default settings:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />
```

But the icon that gets loaded into my iPhone 5S and the emulator is `icon.png`. In my `platforms/ios/HelloWorld/config.xml` it has:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is it still displaying the Cordova icon?

Comment: I had this problem, to fix it I replaced all of the existing cordova icons with my new icon (for each of the resolutions). They can be found at: `*packagename*\platforms\ios\\*App Name*\Resources\icons`. I then reset the simulator, deleted the old app from the iphone, ran a clean in XCode and then ran build. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a `reopened` issue in cordova.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2606

Steps I used to change my icons:

Android:

1. remove folders (drawable) from android/res folder
2. sencha app build -run native
3. after sencha cmd gives error about missing assets, add your icons in

iPhone:

1. Change it manually in xcode

if someone finds a better solution please let me know. Thank you